# What does "as" mean and which structure is the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, sentence-structure

> Difficult as the outbreak was, we managed to finish it.

This sentence is resembling me something like

> How difficult to pass the exam is, harder to get high mark will.

I don't mean the meaning, I meant structure. So what does "**as**" mean in the first sentence and what is the structure or grammar rule of it?

Comment: Your sentence makes no sense. A version corresponding to the first one would be "Difficult as the exam was, I managed to get high marks in it".

Comment: I don't understand what "to finish an outbreak" means. Perhaps it should be *[As] difficult as the outbreak was, we managed to **contain** it.* Where it's at least *slightly* "unusual" to use ***as*** instead of ***though*** (and slightly *more* unusual not to enunciate the initial ***as*** as per my alternative; they're normally used as a matched pair - ***As** bad **as** it is, it could get worse*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use of 'as' means '*although*'.

- Difficult as the outbreak was, we managed to finish it.
- Although the outbreak was difficult, we managed to finish it.

You'll find this use and definition in the [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as).